# Time limit for Android Benchmark library?

Tags: android, performance, benchmarking

I am using [Android Benchmark library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/benchmark) from Google and something that I have seen is that apparently it times out for slow computations (e.g. parsing a lot of data). This is a sample test:

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val benchmarkRule = BenchmarkRule()

@Test
fun quickTest() {
    benchmarkRule.measureRepeated {
        Thread.sleep(10)
    }
}

@Test
fun slowTest() {
    benchmarkRule.measureRepeated {
        Thread.sleep(100)
    }
}
```

While `quickTest` gives a result, `slowTest` shows:

```
Timed out waiting for process (<package>) to appear on <device>.
```

Is it possible to extend or remove the timeout?

Comment: Have you found a way to increase the timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your tests depending on how long they might be running.
If you know the test might take longer than 1000ms to complete, use [`@LargeTest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/filters/LargeTest).
For tests that are likely shorter than 1000ms use [`@MediumTest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/filters/MediumTest).
And tests that are very fast, less than 200ms use [`@SmallTest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/filters/SmallTest).